# LDAP Authentication in ASP.NET MVC 4 web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ldap

I am trying to configure LDAP authentication in my ASP.NET MVC 4 application.

The problem I am having is the error message: `Server is not operational`.

I know there were other threads similar to that one, but could someone explain what do the tags mean in the `web.config` file, so that I know what information should I provide?

Also, the LDAP in my case uses SSL. How can I specify that?

My current connection string is as follows:

```
<add name="LDAPConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://DIRECTORY_ADDRESS:PORT/<BASE DN>"/>
```

My MembershipProvider is:

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider"
                   type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
                   connectionStringName="LDAPConnectionString"
                   connectionProtection="None"
                   connectionUsername="<MY-USERNAME-FOR-LDAP>"
                   connectionPassword="<MY-USER-PASSWORD-FOR-LDAP>"
                   attributeMapUsername="<NO IDEA WHAT THAT IS>"
                   enableSearchMethods="True" />
```

Does that make sense? I use the directory address, my username and password to login using  `jxplorer` and I can see the directory structure correctly.

Also, is the public key something I should change or is it Microsoft's property?

What exactly do the tags mean?

Comment: Are you attempting to connect to an arbitrary LDAP server or Active Directory? I'd personally recommend using an STS service such as ADFS to handle the authentication and then ADFS will then handle the LDAP/SQL/AD connections for you - but then again - it requires a bit of setup. You might also want to check out http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262069(v=office.12).aspx -- Also - windows authentication for ASP.net applications will utilize AD if the server is joined to the domain.

Comment: I am trying to connect to Active Directory. Currently I keep getting the error "Unable to establish secure connection with a server". I need to use Secure attribute as it connects only via SSL. Everything else seems correct. I can access the directory via LDAP browser

Answer (score 0):

If u r trying to connect to Secure LDAP, u need to specify exicitly port 636 (default secure ldap port).
Otherwise, the default port 389 will be used to connect to ldap server